# If someone has your VPN password and email address, can they decrypt your VPN traffic?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

VPN encrypts your traffic all around.  So let's say someone knows your VPN email/password.  Would this give them the ability to decrypt all your communications?

Answer (score 2):

The password used for authentication does not directly allow an attacker to obtain the plaintext traffic. If you use a TLS- or IPsec-based VPN, the key for encrypting the traffic is not derived from the password in any way. Moreover, in a properly configured VPN, it is not feasible (with current technology) to decrypt past traffic due to [perfect forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy). The encryption keys are calculated ad-hoc with a key agreement algorithm like Diffie-Hellman and deleted afterwards.

However, if the e-mail address and password are not just used for VPN authentication but also allow the user to change the VPN configuration, alter the network settings or access the VPN server in some way, then an attacker may very well be able to sabotage the encryption. For example, they may purposely choose weak cryptographic algorithms or capture the plaintext traffic as it flows through the VPN server. This depends on how exactly the VPN infrastructure is set up.

Answer (score 0):

This would refer to a VPN provider, and would ultimately depend on their infrastructure setup - namely the following:

1. Whether or not secret key or TLS authentication were used (optional layer for user/pass authentication in addition).
2. Whether or not the VPN provider protects these fields within their provider UI, and whether they force new profile creation upon modification.

While your tag refers to OpenVPN, explicitly, these concepts would apply to any modern VPN provider utilizing Wireguard or OpenVPN.

As for **#1**:

- [OpenVPN Cryptographic Layer](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/openvpn-cryptographic-layer/): Shows the different options available for cryptographic imperatives set by the tunnel.
- [OpenVPN Alternative Authentication Methods](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/using-alternative-authentication-methods/): Allows for the ability to require an additional layer of login, utilizing a username/password combination utilizing `auth-user-pass-verify`.

As the above relates to **#2**:

- Should you choose a pre-shared key and the individual(s) are able to obtain that through whatever infrastructure the provider uses, then it is plausible they could do so if they were on the wire intercepting your traffic, but not by having your username/password alone.

  - If the `auth-user-pass-verify` is used in combination to a pre-shared key, then they would be able to get around this check, assuming they also have a copy of the key.
- Should TLS authentication be used, then no, they would only have access to your provider interface and have the ability to change or use your service, but your communications would be protected by [Perfect Forward Secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy).

All of the above considered, the other thing to note is that even if they were not able to decrypt your traffic they could:

- Abuse a service you are likely a paying customer for.
- Impersonate your traffic, in case you have any firewall rules that are based on your specific OpenVPN tunnels.